# cmd script for ping to find average, loss and IP

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I look through stackoverflow, found several similar topics bot no one from them wasn't about cmd
The question is:
I have a website, for example route4me.com and I need to ping it and save into file only: IP, %loss and average time
Can anybody explain how to use tockens and delims since I'm total noob.
Found an article, that explains how to:

> Let's have a closer look at the output of the PING command:
>
> we want the (unknown) second word from the first line (actually, the
>   second line, because the first line is blank) that first line contains
>   the (known) IP address enclosed in square brackets [10.100.0.14] none
>   of the other lines contain the IP address enclosed in square brackets,
>   nor any other string in square brackets First let's mark (yellow
>   highlights) the boundaries of the requested word REMOTE_PC:
>
> Pinging REMOTE_PC [10.100.0.14] with 32 bytes of data:
>
> Reply from 10.100.0.14: bytes=32 time<10ms TTL=128
>
> Ping statistics for 10.100.0.14:  Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4,
>   Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>     Minimum = 0ms, Maximum =  0ms, Average =  0ms This makes our choice
>   for the delimiters, delims, quite obvious: a space. If we mark (yellow
>   highlights) all spaces, we can easily see which tokens are available:
>
> Pinging REMOTE_PC [10.100.0.14] with 32 bytes of data:
>
> token=1  token=2     token=3      4  5    6   7    8 In this case,
>   we're only interested in tokens 2 and 3:
>
> token 2 is the requested computer name token 3 can be used to check if
>   we're dealing with the correct line: it should equal our original IP
>   address enclosed in square brackets So we're only interested in the
>   tokens 2 and 3:
>
> Pinging REMOTE_PC [10.100.0.14] with 32 bytes of data:
>
> ```
>      token=2     token=3 This leads us to the following command line:
> ```
>
> FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims= " %%A IN ('PING -a %1') DO IF "%%B"=="[%1]"
>   SET PC=%%A %1 is the value of the first command line argument passed
>   to our batch file. In our case, the IP address to be investigated.
>
> IF "%%B"=="[%1]" checks if the third word (token=3) equals the
>   original IP address (%1) enclosed in square brackets ([%1]). If we
>   were to skip this test, the end result for token 2 would be the equal
>   sign (=) from the last line (just try it). If the test matches, the
>   second word (token=2) is stored in a variable named PC.
>
> Note that the first token specified (token 2) is stored in the
>   variable specified (%%A), and the following token specified (token 3)
>   in the following variable (in this case: %%B).
>
> Our batch file thus far:
>
> @ECHO OFF FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims= " %%A IN ('PING -a %1') DO IF
>   "%%B"=="[%1]" SET PC=%%A SET PC The last line, SET PC, displays the
>   actual value of the variable PC. I added it for debugging purposes.
>   (Actually, SET PC will display all variables whose names begin with
>   "PC".)
>   But for me this is all totally new.

Comment: Why ever you think you need to do this, pinging a web server is not a reliable measure for server health. Responding to pings is unrelated to serving resources. Pinging `microsoft.com` will time out, for example, while the web server at the same address properly serves resources.

Comment: @АлександрЛитвин IInspectable is right, use `owsadm.exe`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768012.aspx

Comment: Please apply [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)!

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down.

---

Basically, tokens are parts of a string and delims(delimiter) are the text to separate the tokens. Consider this example:

```
set str=This.String.Is.Separated.By.Fullstops

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ("%str%") do echo %%a %%b
```

The `for` loops will separate the text by `.`, and now the text are formatted like so:

```
Tokens: 1    2      3  4         5  6
Text  : This String Is Separated By Fullstops
```

and we only need the first two tokens, which is `This` and `String`. `echo %%a` will return `This`, and `echo %%b` will return the `String`. But `echo %%c` will not return `Is`, as the `for` loop only process the first two tokens as stated in `"tokens=1,2`.

---

Back to the `for` loop.

```
FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims= " %%A IN ('PING -a %1') DO IF "%%B"=="[%1]" SET PC=%%A
```

This time, the `for` loops only get the result of the command `PING -a %1`. The result will be:

```
 Tokens: 1       2         3             4    5  6     7  8

 Text  : Pinging REMOTE_PC [10.100.0.14] with 32 bytes of data:
```

and we only take the `2nd` token. Remember, even though token 2 does not seems to be `%%A`, but since in the tokens settings, we've set the first outputted variable to be the text with the 2nd token.

The `IF` statement checks if the 2nd outputted variable with token 3, which is:

```
[10.100.0.14]
```

and this equal to the first command-line argument. If so, it set `PC` to the variable with token 1, which is `REMOTE_PC`, your PC name.

---

To get the information you need, we would introduce another setting called `skip`.`Skip` defines how many lines to skip, and read the line after it.

```
for /f "tokens=11 skip=8 delims= " %%a in ('ping -a google.com') do echo %%a
```

This should get you the loss percentage(maybe not because I don't use the Russian language on my PC.) Feel free to adjust it and make it work for you.

Comment: Thanks for rapid answer, but please forget about example that I gave in quotation ) Lets switch to task, ping route4me.com returns following

Comment: @АлександрЛитвин I'm adding the solution to your problem.

Comment: sorry for stupid question but where I should put this: for /f "tokens=11 skip=8 delims= " %%a in ('ping -a google.com') do echo %%a after ping.exe route4me.com or in another place? and where put saving into file? Also skip = 8 skips 8 rows and gives me value of 9th row?

Comment: For loops will process the command and echo the result immediately, so you place it where you want to have the result. According to my knowledge so far, you’ve correctly understand how skip works.

Comment: Sorry, can't get simply things. I'm starting bat file with this code: ping.exe route4me.com | for /f "tokens=11 skip=8 delims= " %%a in ('ping -a google.com') do echo %%a >> E:\ping.txt  and it gives me opened cmd(actually process doesn't response) and I even can't stop that process by task manager

Comment: Nope. You don't need  `ping.exe route4me.com |`

Comment: something wrong with tokens: your code gives me (0%  , ok let's add token 12, nothing is changed. 13 - also nothing. How?

Comment: That means that you need to output multiple tokens, or just set 0% to a variable, and `echo Loss: %var%`

Comment: Note: you `set` statement should be `set var=%%a%`, as `%` requires apecial escaping.

Comment: for /f "tokens=11,13 skip=8 delims= " %%a in ('ping.exe -a route4me.com') do echo  Loss=%%a    >> E:\res.txt gives  Loss=(0% how to remove brackets?

Comment: The simple way: set %%a to a variable named `Loss`, then after the loop, do `set Loss=%Loss:(=%`, and the third line:  `echo %loss% > file`

Comment: and how to deal with multiple lines: for /f "tokens=9,11  skip=10 delims= " %%a in ('ping.exe -a route4me.com') do echo  Average=%%a    >> E:\res.txt this does exactly what I need, shows average but if I add this to previous code it'll show only result for first line of the code

Comment: Multi-lines will be harder to deal, you could use `if` statements to check if it contains the info you want, or `echo` the entire result into file, then process it.

Comment: how to do it with echo?

Comment: Try using the replace function in `findstr`, but that will be confusing to you.

Comment: set %%a to a variable named Loss what do you mean in this case? write Loss=%%aa ? and where after delims?

Comment: For ... do set loss=%%a

Comment: Thanks again Steve! This echo off
for /f "tokens=4 skip=7 delims= " %%a in ('ping.exe -a route4me.com') do echo  %%a    >> E:\res.txt
for /f "tokens=10 skip=8 delims= " %%a in ('ping.exe -a route4me.com') do echo  Lost=%%a    >> E:\res.txt
for /f "tokens=9,11  skip=10 delims= " %%a in ('ping.exe -a route4me.com') do echo  Average time=%%a    >> E:\res.txt almost works, the problem is it shows IP  several times. Maybe I should chane %%a to something else?

Comment: It seems there are some issues with  positioning the for loops. I can't see through the congested text.

Comment: @echo off for /f "tokens=4 skip=7 delims= " %%a in ('ping.exe -a route4me.com') do echo %%a >> E:\res.txt for /f "tokens=10 skip=8 delims= " %%a in ('ping.exe -a route4me.com') do echo Lost=%%a >> E:\res.txt for /f "tokens=9,11 skip=10 delims= " %%a in ('ping.exe -a route4me.com') do echo Average time=%%a >> E:\res.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :get route4me.com
call :get microsoft.com
call :get google.com
goto :eof
:get
REM set a default value for 'avrg':
set "avrg= ---"
REM do the ping one time...:
>temp ping %1
REM ... and process the output several times to collect the data:
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in (temp) do set "ip=%%a"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=( " %%a in ('find "(" temp') do set "loss=%%a"
for /f "tokens=4 delims==" %%a in ('find "ms, " temp') do set "avrg=%%a"
echo %1,%ip%,%loss%,%avrg:~1%
```

The first `for` loop gets the IP.
There will be only one line containing `[` and `]`, so we can safely process the whole line without another line overwriting our result (no other line will have a `token`2).

The second `for` loop gets the loss percentage.
It's the only line containing `(` and `)`, but this time, we have to use `token` 1. so the next line would destroy our token. So we use `find` to filter only this line (every line will have a first token).

The third `for` loop gets the average value.
Again, we need a filter the line (I'm using `ms,`, hoping it's international; the other two should work in every language)
If there is no such line, the tokens keeps empty, so the `set` will not execute and the default value is kept.
(trying to keep it language independend is also the reason for the delimiter `=` only in the last `for`loop and removing the space afterwards with `%avrg:~1%`)

Working with a temporary file doesn't only make it faster (one ping instead of three), but also ensures, the data is consistent (get all values from the same `ping` command).

I prefer filtering over `skip`ping, because you can never be sure, if the lines to skip are the same in every case (responsive address vs. unresponsive address)

Comment: Thanks Stephan but code above creates empty temp file ( But anyway I have to write solution by myself, not copy-paste from here and your solution seems difficult for me, because I don't understand part before first for at all

Comment: I appreciate your attitude. There are way to many "Gimme-de-codez" people around here. There is no way `>temp ping ...` creates an empty file - except you have a `ping.bat`

Comment: Also list line echo %1,%ip%,%loss%,%avrg:~1% seems displays only values without name of variable and I need names of them

Comment: `echo IP=%ip%`, `echo Loss=%loss%`, `echo AverageTime=%avrg%`

Comment: Thanks it appeared pretty simple.